# How do I make the image go behind the menu bar when I scroll down in html & css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make the image go behind the menu bar when I scroll down in html & css? i have tried some things but it does not help me out please help me if possible as this i really important for me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrP3Z.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff3cc;
}

.menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: "FuturaMedium", Futura, "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: "FuturaMedium", Futura, "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  color: #ff8c8c;
}

.active {
  color: #a5e5ff !important;
}

.slidershow {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.bar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

input[name="r"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#r1:checked~.s1 {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#r2:checked~.s1 {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#r3:checked~.s1 {
  margin-left: -40%;
}

.about {
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30pt;
  line-height: 60px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
}

p {
  font-family: Optima, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.shop-btn {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 680px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.shop-btn-inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#42455a, #42455a), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #fd00da, #19d7f8);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.shop-btn-inner .fa {
  padding: 18px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.small {
  margin: auto 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #96ff8c;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vista Digital Cameras</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
      <h3>VISTA DIGITAL</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="active">HOME</li>
        <li>CAMERAS</li>
        <li>SERVICES</li>
        <li>NEWS</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="slidershow middle">
      <div class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
        <div class="slide s1">
          <img src="images/x-a5%20brown.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="images/x-a5%20black.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="images/x-a5%20turquoise.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="about">
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <p>Vista Digital is a company engaged in the field of photography founded in 2000. In accordance with our vision and mission, we are committed to help develop the world of photography in Indonesia with our concept, the 3S, namely: Sales, Services,
        and School.</p>
      <h2>Sales</h2>
      <p>We make every effort to meet the needs of photographers by providing all photographic equipments, ranging from core equipments to supporting accessories for your photography needs, from all brands both original and third-party. Our knowledgeable
        staff will help you with product knowledge and technical and maintenance matters in the use of your photographic equipments.</p>
      <h2>Services</h2>
      <p>We also provide repairment/maintenance services for your photography products for all brands, supported by highly experienced equipments and technical personnel. </p>
      <h2>School</h2>
      <p>Not only do we focus on Sales and Services, we also provide solutions for those of you who want to explore the field of photograph quickly and effectively. We provide adequate facilities, namely comfortable classrooms, studios, materials, and models,
        as well as tutors who are certainly very competent in the field of photography.</p>

      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
        ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-btn">
      <div class="shop-btn-inner"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
      </div>
      <small style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; color: #96ff8c" ;><b>SHOP NOW</b></small>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i tried everything

How do I make the image go behind the menu bar when I scroll down in html & css?

Answer (score 2):

Please look into the `z-index` property.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

In your CSS simply add:

```
z-index:1
```

To your menu class.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan MDN is also often outdated, so take care to use that one as gospel. And not all W3Schools pages have incorrect information. This one has, but not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to learn more about z-index.

Freecodecamp offers a very good explanation on z-index:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3/

But for a quick fix for your case, you can add a z-index to your `.menu`.

```
.menu{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `.slidershow { z-index: -999;}`

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff3cc;
}

.menu{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu ul{
    display: inline-flex;
    float: right;
    margin: 30px;
    font-family: "FuturaMedium",Futura,"Century Gothic",sans-serif;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h3{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: "FuturaMedium",Futura,"Century Gothic",sans-serif;
    color: #ff8c8c;
}

.active{
    color: #a5e5ff !important;
}

.slidershow{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.middle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.navigation{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
}

.bar{
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar:hover{
    background: #fff; 
}

input[name="r"]{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slides{
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#r1:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: 0;
}

#r2:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -20%;
}

#r3:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -40%;
}

.about{
    margin-top: 100px;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

h1{
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30pt;
    line-height: 60px;
}

h2{
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
}

p{
    font-family: Optima, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.shop-btn{
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 680px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.shop-btn-inner{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#42455a,#42455a),radial-gradient(circle at top left,#fd00da,#19d7f8);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

.shop-btn-inner .fa{
    padding: 18px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.small{
    margin: auto 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #96ff8c;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.slidershow{
    z-index: -999;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menu">
          <h3>VISTA DIGITAL</h3>
          <ul>
              <li class="active">HOME</li>
              <li>CAMERAS</li>
              <li>SERVICES</li>
              <li>NEWS</li>
              <li>CONTACT</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="slidershow middle">
          <div class="slides">
              <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
              <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
              <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
              <div class="slide s1">
                  <img src="images/x-a5%20brown.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                  <img src="images/x-a5%20black.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                  <img src="images/x-a5%20turquoise.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navigation">
              <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
              <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
              <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
          </div>
      </div>

       <div class="about">
          <h1>About Us</h1>
          <p>Vista Digital is a company engaged in the field of photography founded in 2000. In accordance with our vision and mission, we are committed to help develop the world of photography in Indonesia with our concept, the 3S, namely: Sales, Services, and School.</p>
          <h2>Sales</h2>
          <p>We make every effort to meet the needs of photographers by providing all photographic equipments, ranging from core equipments to supporting accessories for your photography needs, from all brands both original and third-party. Our knowledgeable staff will help you with product knowledge and technical and maintenance matters in the use of your photographic equipments.</p>
          <h2>Services</h2>
          <p>We also provide repairment/maintenance services for your photography products for all brands, supported by highly experienced equipments and technical personnel. </p>
          <h2>School</h2>
          <p>Not only do we focus on Sales and Services, we also provide solutions for those of you who want to explore the field of photograph quickly and effectively. We provide adequate facilities, namely comfortable classrooms, studios, materials, and models, as well as tutors who are certainly very competent in the field of photography.</p>

           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-btn">
          <div class="shop-btn-inner"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
          </div>
          <small style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; color: #96ff8c";><b>SHOP NOW</b></small>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `z-index` on your menu element

```
.menu{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000; // any number higher than one
}
```

NB: any change will not be visible for you because the menu back-ground color obacity

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index:1;` to .menu class.

```
  .menu{
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index:1;  /* Add this */
    }
```

`z-index`:**The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order will always appears in front of an element with a lower stack order.**

```css
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff3cc;
}

.menu{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
}

.menu ul{
    display: inline-flex;
    float: right;
    margin: 30px;
    font-family: "FuturaMedium",Futura,"Century Gothic",sans-serif;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h3{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: "FuturaMedium",Futura,"Century Gothic",sans-serif;
    color: #ff8c8c;
}

.active{
    color: #a5e5ff !important;
}

.slidershow{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.middle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.navigation{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
}

.bar{
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar:hover{
    background: #fff; 
}

input[name="r"]{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slides{
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#r1:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: 0;
}

#r2:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -20%;
}

#r3:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -40%;
}

.about{
    margin-top: 100px;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

h1{
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30pt;
    line-height: 60px;
}

h2{
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
}

p{
    font-family: Optima, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.shop-btn{
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 680px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.shop-btn-inner{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#42455a,#42455a),radial-gradient(circle at top left,#fd00da,#19d7f8);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

.shop-btn-inner .fa{
    padding: 18px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.small{
    margin: auto 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #96ff8c;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
<h3>VISTA DIGITAL</h3>
<ul>
<li class="active">HOME</li>
<li>CAMERAS</li>
<li>SERVICES</li>
<li>NEWS</li>
<li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="slidershow middle">
<div class="slides">
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
<div class="slide s1">
<img src="images/x-a5%20brown.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="slide">
<img src="images/x-a5%20black.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="slide">
<img src="images/x-a5%20turquoise.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
<label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
<label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
<label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="about">
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>Vista Digital is a company engaged in the field of photography founded in 2000. In accordance with our vision and mission, we are committed to help develop the world of photography in Indonesia with our concept, the 3S, namely: Sales, Services, and School.</p>
<h2>Sales</h2>
<p>We make every effort to meet the needs of photographers by providing all photographic equipments, ranging from core equipments to supporting accessories for your photography needs, from all brands both original and third-party. Our knowledgeable staff will help you with product knowledge and technical and maintenance matters in the use of your photographic equipments.</p>
<h2>Services</h2>
<p>We also provide repairment/maintenance services for your photography products for all brands, supported by highly experienced equipments and technical personnel. </p>
<h2>School</h2>
<p>Not only do we focus on Sales and Services, we also provide solutions for those of you who want to explore the field of photograph quickly and effectively. We provide adequate facilities, namely comfortable classrooms, studios, materials, and models, as well as tutors who are certainly very competent in the field of photography.</p>

<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
<div class="shop-btn">
<div class="shop-btn-inner"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
</div>
<small style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; color: #96ff8c";><b>SHOP NOW</b></small>
</div>
</div>
```